# ibm cloud for integration Telemetry Enable

Tags: ibm-cloud, mqtt, ibm-mq, telemetry

I am using ibm cloud pak for integration version 3.0.0.
I deployed an MQ instance into my Openshift Cluster.
when I check my new created instance information it says: "telemetry not supported"

[image]

But I want my instance to support MQTT protocol.

is there anything I am missing? what can I do? thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not installed by default, which means that to install it you will need to customise the container.

You will need to clone the IBM MQ Container - https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-container

and ask for MQTT to be installed by changing the line

```
export genmqpkg_incmqxr=0
```

to

```
export genmqpkg_incmqxr=1
```

in the file `install-mq.sh`. Then follow the build instructions to create the container image.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I deploy my pod through the cloud pak console. is it enough to clone it, change it, and point to my own git?

is it possible to add mqtt to an already-existing instance?

the official ibm git I am using is: https://github.com/IBM/charts/tree/master/entitled/ibm-mqadvanced-server-integration-prod

Comment: What you say sounds reasonable, but I haven't been through the process of using the helm charts to deploy MQ so can't say for sure. I would verify whether the helm chart points at an existing container image or builds one. I suspect it points at an existing one. A quick glance at the helm chart suggest it isn't building an image, I can't say for sure, but I think you need to build the image with your modifications.

Comment: Just a heads up on the modifications. One of my colleagues suggests that there is a bug in the container build and 'when I installed XR I seemed to get FTE and when I installed FTE I seemed to get XR'. He is verifying if it is a bug and will request a fix if it is.